# Rails create one or create multiple records from a range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a class called IP, with an `:address` attribute, and two virtual attributes: `:start_ip` and `:end_ip`

```
class IP < ActiveRecord::Base
  # address attribute is saved in database
  # start_ip and end_ip are virtual attribute, used in my form
  attr_accessor :start_ip, :end_ip
end
```

I've got a form that lets me enter a single IP (into the :address field) OR a range of addresses into the fields for my virtual attributes (:start_ip and :end_ip).

Everything works fine if I enter single IP in the :address field.

If I enter a range of addresses (lets say it spans 5 addresses), then I want to create IP records for each of the addresses in the range, AND I think it might be best to reject the current record as it won't have an entry in its :address field since I entered a range.

So I figure I need a before_save callback:

```
before_save :range_given?

def range_given?
  create!([@start_ip..@end_ip])
end
```

But it's not quite right.

How can I tell rails to forget about the currently instantiated (and validated) record, and instead create 5 new records setting each ones address attribute to an IP from the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy to fix this:

```
def create_from_range      
  # We are dealing with a range, so lets
  # turn both ends into IPAddr objects
  # so that we can do some Ruby magic on them
  start_addr = IPAddr.new(start_ip)
  end_addr   = IPAddr.new(end_ip)

  # Now that we have the start and end points of
  # of our range, we can call "to_a" on it, which
  # will give us a list of all the IPs from start to end
  range = (start_addr..end_addr).to_a

  # We need to shift the first value off the array, 
  # and assign it's address to the record we are
  # currently in the middle of creating, as it does 
  # not have an address yet
  #
  # No need to call save on this as we are in a 
  # before_save filter but you might need to do
  # that, depending on your domain
  first_ip   = range.shift
  self.address = first_ip.to_s

  # Now we loop through the remaining items in our range  
  # (array of IPs) and create a new record for each one
  range.each{ |ip| IPcreate! address: ip.to_s } 
end
```

Easy, no messing about.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller at the `create` action you can write something like this:

```
(params[:start_ip]..params[:end_ip]).each do |ip|
  IP.create!(address: ip)
end
```

Add the code you need.

PD. Maybe you should rethink your domain models, because an ip address is different than an ip range

Comment: Thanks, see my answer for the solution I chose. In the end I wanted to avoid doing this from the controller, so I've got a before_save callback that does creates the IPs.